# regex - Find all strings not matching a pattern

Tags: regex, regex-negation

We receive a file daily with thousands of lines of data.  Occasionally, a few lines will be messed up, causing an automated process to fail.  When this happens, it can be difficult to find the errors.

I'd like to use a regular expression to find anything not conforming to the files usual structure.  All lines are supposed to look like the following:

```
ABC|SomeText|MoreText
DEF|SomeText|MoreText
ABC|SomeText|MoreText
GHI|SomeText|MoreText
DEF|SomeText|MoreText
```

So a regex that flags lines that don't begin with 3 letters and a pipebar.
In the below example, it would flag line 3.

```
ABC|SomeText|MoreText
DEF|Some
Text|MoreText
ABC|SomeText|MoreText
GHI|SomeText|MoreText
DEF|SomeText|MoreText
```

Any help would be appreciated, I've been struggling with this for a while.

Many thanks

Comment: What is the tool/programming language?

Comment: Notepad++ should be added as the question tag if you are using it. Notepad++ uses Boost regex library, it is not PCRE, but is close to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be very helpful to explain what dialect of regular expressions you are using. For example, if you are using grep, you can just use the `-v` option to invert the sense and then just write a normal regular expression, like so:

```
grep -v -E '^[A-Z]{3}\|[^|]*\|'
```

Otherwise if you can't invert the sense but you have a system capable of using [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (like Perl) you could do the following:

```
grep -P '^(?![A-Z]{3}\|[^|]*\|)'
```

The `(?!...)` part makes the negative lookahead. So this will match any line where the beginning isn't followed by three capital letters, a bar, some text and then another bar.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Neil.  I'm not sure of the dialect.  Currently I'm using the regex feature of notepad++ to search through the files.  Not sure if that helps.  I'll give these a try!

Comment: Apparently notepad++ uses PCRE (Perl-compatible regular expressions) so it should support the second one with negative lookahead. Good luck!

Comment: You're quite correct, it was #2 for the win.  Works like a charm!  Sorry, this was my first question ... where do I toggle that as the correct answer?

Comment: Apparently there should be a tick mark underneath the score for the answer that you can click on. Actually, I've never asked a question before so this is new to me too ☺ http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

For example, using awk:

```
awk '!/^[a-zA-Z]{3}\|/' input.txt
```

will display the 'flagged' lines.

```
awk '/^[a-zA-Z]{3}\|/' in.txt
```

will display the correct lines.

Comment: Thanks Wroniasty, I'll give this a try!